# Forecasting using a dynamic factor model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, macroeconomics

I am doing a project of econometrics, now-casting quarterly GDP using a dynamic factor model applied on monthly macro-economic variables. I have tried to read through supporting literature on my research but I do not understand the practical steps to follow when implementing the model in any econometric software.

Comment: Do you mean the model by Peña & Poncela ["Forecasting with nonstationary dynamic factor models."](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407603001982) *Journal of Econometrics* 119.2 (2004): 291-321? I had trouble following it step by step some time ago, and I actually gave up that time. The description of the model building procedure is slightly vague, IMHO.

Comment: @ Hardy, the question is a general one. I ,however, did not come across the cited paper.

Comment: OK, then be aware that there are different models sharing the same name. (The one I refer to above is actually a less popular version, I believe.) Consider referring to a particular paper to indicate what kind of dynamic factor model you are interested in.